# AoCG2021 Day 9: Spiral memory stress test

Tags: code-golf, grid

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2017 Day 3](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/3), Part 2.

---

You come across an experimental new kind of memory stored on an infinite two-dimensional grid.

Each square on the grid is allocated in a spiral pattern starting at a location marked 1 and then counting up while spiraling outward. For example, the first few squares are allocated like this:

```
17  16  15  14  13
18   5   4   3  12
19   6   1   2  11
20   7   8   9  10
21  22  23---> ...
```

As a stress test on the system, the programs here clear the grid and then store the value 1 in square 1. Then, in the same allocation order as shown above, they store the sum of the values in all adjacent squares, *not* including diagonals.

So, the first few squares' values are chosen as follows:

- Square 1 starts with the value 1.
- Square 2 has only one adjacent filled square (with value 1), so it also stores 1.
- Square 3 is the same (diagonal neighbors don't count), so it also stores 1.
- Square 4 has squares 1 and 3 as neighbors and stores the sum of their values, 2.
- Square 5 has square 4 as its only neighbor, so it gets the value 2.

Once a square is written, its value does not change. Therefore, the first few squares would receive the following values:

```
 12   12   10    8    7
 14    2    2    1    7
 17    3    1    1    6
 20    3    4    5    5
 20   23   27--->   ...
```

What is the first value written that is at least as large as the input (a positive integer)?

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
9 -> 10
18 -> 20
50 -> 55
100 -> 111
200 -> 214
500 -> 552
1000 -> 1070
1070 -> 1070
```

Comment: This is [A334742](https://oeis.org/A334742).

Comment: May I use 0-indexed input?

Comment: @tsh No, the task is not a sequence.

Comment: @Bubbler Ah, I misread the question as output the n-th element of the sequence... (And try to golf it until I find out I cannot pass testcases...)

Answer (score 9):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⟦¹⟧ηＷ‹⌈ηθ«⊞υη≔ＥηＥ⮌υ§μλυ≔Ｅ§υ⁰Σ…§υ±¹⊕λη»Ｉ⌊Φη¬‹ιθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/LCsIwEDzbr8hxAxXas6dSEAq2iB7FQ6yLCSRpm4cPxG@PaasH3cuyOzuzMy1npu2YDKHSvXeNVyc0MNBVUlgrLhoO@TElPM43LiQS2KC1ULO7UF4BpykZKCXPZLH1loOfTxcfbs164CkZ2w6vaCyCj4zCVfqMd1ApkZTGhf/jfA@iXBbhffxUPlqJJe9@wAYvzCHko0alW4MKtcMzjKp0tvJKtkZoByWzDmqhJ9trIV1MGa01nZsTiSnIWKsQ8iwLy6t8Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the target.

```
≔⟦¹⟧η
```

Start with the middle cell.

```
Ｗ‹⌈ηθ«
```

Repeat until the target is reached.

```
⊞υη
```

Add the latest row to the grid.

```
≔ＥηＥ⮌υ§μλυ
```

Rotate the grid.

```
≔Ｅ§υ⁰Σ…§υ±¹⊕λη
```

Take the cumulative sum of the new last row.

```
»Ｉ⌊Φη¬‹ιθ
```

Output the smallest value not lower than the target.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>39</sup> 37 bytes

```
{{y(<:<./@#]),|:@|.@(,+/\@{:)^:y,.1}}
```

*-2 thanks to Olius's idea of using direct definition `{{ }}` instead of a tacit verb*

YAPONA - Yet Another Port of Neil's Answer.

To save bytes, we repeat the iteration `<input>` times -- which is always enough, and usually returns much more than we need -- then find the first valid number within that result.

No TIO for this one because the TIO J version is too old and doesn't have `{{ }}` yet.  I tested locally though and it works.  TIO'd tacit version below.

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 39 bytes tacit solution with TIO

```
(<:<./@#&,])]1&(](,~+/\.@{.)@|:@|.),.@1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcMxCoQwEAXQ3lN8FDTB7DgjCBpcGBCsrKxNJYrYeIAVr571wTtjSsWOr0cBB4Z/fwjDPI3R9L6nSrPcBRskN8G4p6wW0h9Zvb3eZB2pRJts63FhT0sIanSQFg1DmFG/G@b4Bw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>80 78 75</s> 66 bytes

```ruby
->n,*r{(n+a=1).times{|x|r<<a;(1..x/2).map{a<n&&r<<a+=r[1-x-x]}};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PR6uoWiNPO9HWUFOvJDM3tbi6pqKmyMYm0VrDUE@vQt9IUy83saA60SZPTQ0krG1bFG2oW6FbEVtba51Y@79AIdpQx0jHUsfQQsfUQMfQwEDHCIhNDcBsEGFuEAsyQkMtTfM/AA)

#### Explanation (if it still matters):

- We need at most (n+1) segments to find the number (n=2,3,4 can't be found on the 2nd 3rd and 4th segment).
- Length of segments (removing corners) is 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 ...
- In the corners we can reuse the previous value: x[n]=x[n-1]
- For the other cells: x[n]=x[n-1]+x[n-m] where m is increased by 2 for every side.

Maybe there is a way to skip the corners? we don't need the repeated values to find the final result, only to calculate the other intermediate values.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>96</strike>, <strike>94</strike>, <strike>92</strike> (@dingledooper), 90 bytes (@xnor)

```python
def f(i):
 *T,s=1,;t=T,[1],[1]
 while i>s:T,*t=*t,[s:=s+x*(i>s)for x in[0,*T,0]]
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBBbsMgELzvK1acwN1W4NZq6oi8gpvrQ6XaClKKEVA19efdxWkOy87szMCK@FvOS3g@xLRtn9OMs/SqB2wcZWvoWKyjwYy1AH/O/jKhP@XeUVNsU2jIvc0P10byUM1Lwiv6MGjiuB45kabynQLmzVkhhMHHExpoa2vhbWcazGHnGjpdQdeB0Tsyhr032JoXlv/1thpuDv3KeT7uhB8BZ4evjyh9KFSecrz4IkXVhVJYVyy8Irq78h6EGqHOPS270q@2fsIxJr5CelpptXZRsP0B)

Older versions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBbsMgEEX3c4oRKyCkAlqrqSNyCnbUi0q1FaQEIyBq6su74DQb@H/en2FE/C3nObweYlrX73HCiXrWA3IrslHiWIyzw05z59QwAP6c/WVEf8q9FbwYXoTLvcm7O6e1yKY54R19cFLUAbJ1pLHcUsC8WkMIUbg/oQLdLg0fm5OgDpuX0Mkmug6U3JRSNfuQWr1V/M91CzwS8r321@Np6iNgjbt@RepDEeUlx4svlDROGMO2Yqkron2Sz0DYAK3uxbyRfjHtG44x1RHUi0UsxswM1j8)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBbsMgEEX3c4oRKyCkAlqrqSNyCnbUi0q1FaQEIyBq6su74DQb@H/en2FE/C3nObweYlrX73HCiXrWA3IrslHiWIyzw05z59QwAP6c/WVEf8q9FbwYXoSjuTd5d@e0Vhmb5oR39MFJUUfI1pPGcksB82oNIUTh/oQKdLs0fGxOgjpsXkInm@g6UHJTStXsQ2r1VvE/1y3wSMj32l@Pp6mPgDXu@hWpD0WUlxwvvlDSOGEM24qlroj2ST4DYQO0uhfzRvrFtI84xlRHUC8WsRgzM1j/AA)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBbsMgEEX3c4oRK6CkAqdWU0fkFOwoi0q1FaQEIyBq6su74DQb@H/en2FE/C3nOewPMa3r9zjhRD0bALkRRWS959Yq54Q6FiudNoA/Z38Z0Z/yYAQvmhdhaR50frlzWquMTXPCO/pgpahDpHOAaSy3FDCvRhNCFO5OqKBrVwcfm5OgDpuX0Msm@h6U3JRSNfuQnXqr@J93LfBIyPfaX4@nqY@A0fb6FakPRZTXHC@@UNI4YQzbiqWuiOZJPgNhDlrdi3kjw6LbVxxjqiOoF4tYtJ4ZrH8)

This keeps a running sum `s` and the four sides of the growing rectangle/spiral double accounting for corners. `T` holds the "active" side, `t` the three others.

Comment: The parentheses around the walrus may be removed, I believe.

Comment: It looks like you can do `t=T,[1],[1]`

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```javascript
n=>eval("for(j=k=0,a=[t=q=1];q<n;)a.push(q+=j--?a[++t-k]:![j=++k>>1]);q")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5NDoIwEAXgvadAVm0q0DY2/uDgQQiLRkEtpKWAXB@BBIgwy/nyXp6Srawf1adsPG2eaZdBpyFKW1kgNzMVUpADPUiIG7DAktDedIilX37rN7IElOfdZUxI4@XJdR8rICSPIpbg0Lq4exhdmyL1C/NCGWIYO/0FgcN2/8Jn4Su5LBm6InYebQitSdCJhFin6GhDIdvMmI2z46ZyMiH4tnPAceRpM7N/Ldj9AA)

#### Commented

This is a version without `eval()` for easier formatting.

```javascript
n => {               // n = input
  for(               // main loop:
    j =              //   j is the length of the current segment minus 1
    k = 0,           //   k is incremented after each segment
                     //   (which means that it holds the number of turns)
                     //   the length of the next segment is floor((k+1)/2)
    a = [            //   a[] is used to store the sequence
      t =            //   t+1-k is the index of the neighbor cell in the
                     //   previous layer of the spiral
      q = 1          //   q is the current value of the sequence
    ];               //
    q < n;           //   we keep going until q >= n
  )                  //
    a.push(          //   append to a[]:
      q +=           //     the updated value of q
        j--          //     decrement j
        ?            //     if we haven't reached the end of the segment:
          a[++t - k] //       increment t and add the value of the
                     //       neighbor cell in the previous layer
        :            //     else (this is a corner):
          ![         //       leave q unchanged
            j =      //       increment k and update j to
            ++k >> 1 //       floor(k/2)
          ]          //
    );               //   end of push()
  return q           // end of for(); return q
}                    //
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 87 bytes

```
n->a=Mat(1);until(d=[b|b<-c,b>=n],s=0;a=Mat(Vecrev(concat(c=[s+=b|b<-a[,1]],a~))));d[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCoMwEER/ZfGU0A0kgtBi1z/otZeQQ4xaBFmD2kKh9NfTWOfwZh5M9MuoHjENQIlV4@nmN2Fk/eRtnERHtv20VxWwbYgdrqTr43Lvw9K/RJg5ZAtk1xP9r96icQ79V@bUnTUu@Rint2BQDcRl5C3PYpcCBsFSIliDUCJcEMwZodK5dUa5o9KHaifTDw)

A port of [@Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238259/9288).

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 91 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,o=p=[X=x=y=0,Y=v=1])=>n>(o[[x+=o[p]?X:X+=Y+(Y=-X),y+=Y]]=v+=o[p=[x+Y,y-X]]|0)?f(n,o):v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7dCoIwHAXw@57Cyw1nbtKojL@@xobsQkyjECcZQ6F3Nz9Aze1q7LdzOK/UpE32ftYfr9L3vO8LQBXRUEMioIUOKJFggCkMURUhnSStCzqpVSxC4YJ0kQRPYNINd6XATAjDJ0k6Tyj1pTguxkYcmj7TVaPL/FjqByoQw/jmDMf3HXb4p2ClYEfXTYrujF1mHGN743Qxzvc5OuPYyawtKwbsZLUuyHlg1046TT1bY4enjfY/)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
1¸¸IFøí¤ηOª}˜ʒI@}ß
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238259/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8NCOQzs83Q7vOLz20JJz2/0Prao9PefUJE@H2sPzgbIWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWilvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w0P7Ti0Izqq0kH58I7Daw8tObfd/9Cq2tNzTk06tM6h9vD8/zr/ow11jHQsdQwtdEwNdAwNDHSMgNjUAMwGEeYGsQA) (the test suite loops until the result is found (`IF` replaced with `[ZI@#`), since looping \$n\$ times will time out for the larger test cases).

**Explanation:**

```python
1¸¸         # Start matrix at center [[1]]
   IF       # Loop the input amount of times:
     øí     #  Rotate the matrix once clockwise:
     ø      #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
      í     #   Reverse each row
       ¤    #  Get the last row (without popping the matrix)
        ηO  #  Get the cumulative sum:
        η   #   Pop and push a list of its prefixes
         O  #   Sum each inner list
          ª #  Add this row to the matrix
    }˜      # After the loop: flatten the matrix to a list
      ʒ     # Filter this list of integers by:
       I@   #  Keep those larger than or equal to the input
      }ß    # After the filter: pop and push the minimum
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

`ʒI@}ß` could alternatively be `I<LKß` (push list \$[1,input)\$, remove those values, minimum) or `{.Δ>‹` (sort, find first \$n\$ which is \$input\lt n+1\$) for the same byte-count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <strike>155</strike> 151 bytes

```rust
|a|{let(mut s,mut v)=(1,vec![0,1,1]);for i in(0..).flat_map(|i|{s+=i/2;(0..1).chain(s-i/2..=s)}){let r=v[i]+v[v.len()-1];v.push(r);if r>=a{return r}}0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLbsMgELznK9Y5RNBgClaiPiynH2JZEYqwguRQF7B7sPl2F6yqDdkDaGZndgdhBuuWVsNNKI0wTBsI1UkHLVSwzGKeAkC3wYEl8RxxhTgZ5SWrGeGEN7hsPw0oCHZGKaZtJ9z5Jno0q3my@0o9F2XscEwv17jE5oGitLLY4zgcTDXWqtmP9Ug7GULkvClH2g/2igwuVQvmVInJSDcYDcZ75pcYslyjxuVI6X5wBIS239LgEAV29dqNFeICx@QfFwSKe/wW@uye4K9BkTBHRuB4TDQsUJyngyNX8EPqXK3Fgzea2Uu6NeCEbX5/I1ZvlHadztB2ev/wkJ8g3lsC6dPLP4OwVhp3ll8Z2rXoaZXhB53f@OUH)

This works by generating [A334742](https://oeis.org/A334742) (the actual numbers in the spiral) using [A265400](https://oeis.org/A265400) (indices of adjacent squares), which is generated using [A004526](https://oeis.org/A004526) (length of each corner, which increases every two rotations).

- -4 bytes by replacing the outer iterator with `for`

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 31 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{⊑≥⟜⊸/∧⥊{⌽˘⍉∾+`⊏⌽}⍟≍≍1}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge+KKkeKJpeKfnPCdlaniirgv4oin4qWKe+KMvcuY4o2J8J2VqeKIvitg4oqP4oy98J2VqX3ijZ/wnZWp4omN4omNMX0KCkbCqDHigL8y4oC/OeKAvzE44oC/NTDigL8xMDDigL8yMDDigL81MDAgI+KAvzEwMDDigL8xMDcwIHRvbyBzbG93Li4gbWF5YmUgdHJ5IG9uIENCUU4K)

Similar idea to Neil's answer. Some combinators come in really handy here.

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 389 bytes

```
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,K=keyof T>=T extends T?keyof T extends K?T:never:0;type b<T,N=[],U=[]>=T extends[infer A,...infer T]?b<T,[...N,...A],[...U,[...N,...A]]>:U;type c<N,A=[[0]],B=A,C=A,D=A,E=b<A>,F=E[number]>=1 extends(F extends N?1:0)?a<Extract<F,N>>:E extends[...{}[],infer L]?c<N,[L,...B],C,[...D,A[0]],E>:0;type M<N,m=[]>=N extends m["length"]?c<[...m,...0[]]>["length"]:M<N,[...m,0]>
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAQwB4AVAGgGkBeAa3R2QDNDyA+W8w9AD3DpEAE0jsA-I2Zse-QSLHVx5AFyJ0AN3SoVABgDcuAoQBGFSgDlaAbQC6lAKo3bXWQKGjrsRC22EAgpQAdCHevqjstuJmVNYhQRbBIf72cSEOlGkJSUEpLioOhvhEAMakif421rq29gBCtIEAwo2UACKtAKK0Zv4clABitJ3WiACuALYm2i60AIy87goAFAOL8qKEFuJzegCU4mSdAqjEJeCkA5YcHCqd6x6QWQDeAL52lGF+ADJRZYnWb45Or2JqZeJtSj+aq1SidW4GIxEACy5UoE2cXAsDwUhAm1gARAAbITwcAACwJf1IWQmOV0dhchJJiDJlNsKlRAPidJqHEw2GK7F0hFohFRc35IEIMoAeuJBcZyAsxaiAExS4AywjyxVEchq0Xi0gATk12t1SPYAGYjRKABzmuUKq3kAAsdtIAFZdE6dS6heQvZ65rpfZhpc69ewAGyetVhv2WwMAdk9PvDkf9mCAA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

```
// Filters a union of tuples for those with the shortest length
type Shortest<T, K = keyof T> = T extends T ? keyof T extends K ? T : never : 0

// Turns [a, b, c, d] into [a, a+b, a+b+c, a+b+c+d]
type CumSum<T, N=[], U=[]> = T extends [infer A,...infer T] ? CumSum<T, [...N, ...A], [...U, [...N, ...A]]> : U

// Extends the spiral one side at a time until one of the numbers is matches N
// If the spiral is
//   a b c d
//   e f g h
//   i j k l
//   '->
// (where g was the start)
// It will be represented as A=[i,j,k,l] ; B=[l,h,d] ; C=[d,c,b,a] ; D=[a,e,i]
// The next iteration will be
//   a b c d
//   e f g h
//   i j k l ^
//   m n o p-'
// Where m=i ; n=m+j ; o=n+k ; p=o+l
// And is represented as A=[p,l,h,d] ; B=[d,c,b,a] ; C=[a,e,i,m] ; D=[m,n,o,p]
// The spiral starts as A=B=C=D=[1] ([[0]] in tuple form)
type Iterate<Cond, A=[[0]], B=A, C=A, D=A, New=CumSum<A>, NewNums=New[number]> =
  1 extends (NewNums extends Cond ? 1 : 0)
    // If any of NewNums match Cond, return the shortest of those that do
    ? Shortest<Extract<NewNums, Cond>>
    : New extends [...{}[],infer L]
      // Get the last element of New, and update the spiral sides
      ? Iterate<Cond, [L,...B], C, [...D, A[0]], New>
      // Unreachable
      : 0

type Main<N,M=[]> =
  N extends M["length"]
    // If M's length is N, return Iterate where Cond is >= M
    ? Iterate<[...M,...0[]]>["length"]
    // Increment M and repeat
    : Main<N, [...M, 0]>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 76 bytes

```
Min@Cases[Nest[Reverse@Append[#,Accumulate@Last@#]&,{{1}},#],b_/;b>=#,2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcdBC4IwGIDhv/LBYKcvnIJQhDLpWhFdx4hpnyg0ETe7yM4d@6n9hGV0eV5ea3xH1vi@MbGFIp76QR6MI6fO5Ly60pMmR7IaRxruimHVNLOdH8aTPBrnJdOf94vjsqQhINNY35J9XRYMM83jZeoHrxhsSmgV0xo4JBKWFCFD2CGkW4RcrBUr2Y9c/FeE@AU)

A port of [@Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/238259/9288).

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 261 bytes

```
f=lambda n,c=[[1],[1],[1]]:c[-1][-1]if c[-1][-1]>=n else(f(n,c[:-1]+[(c[-1]+[c[-1][-1]+k[len(c[-1])-1]if len(k:=c[len(c)>4 and -5]+([]if len(c)<4 else[c[-4][0]]))>=len(c[-1])else c[-1][0]])])if all(len(c[-1])<= len(i)for i in c[-3:-1])else f(n,c+[[c[-1][-1]]]))
```

Not a very fancy solution, at each recursive call, builds a side of the spiral square.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5LDoMgEL3KLCHQBH9pa8SLTFhQKykpolE3Pb0FbHUxw8y8D2/6rK/RF7dp3jYjnR4eTw2edxIxU/xXqu7wkqlY1sAxt9JD75aeGBIUWIcTQ5JghgeLvdH1fj/T3SHu71p2O0DbErR/wqVSjOAf72hTJvfoVCoUSlHaytMqYr8sEVM0CLVz5GQ0MjlZasYZLFgf6UV9iFNshmfU@MU2zdavxNllJYOeiOGAGYecw51DduNQifCK0PLYKrGvqV9FMKDbFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 91 bytes

```r
function(x,m=t(1)){while(x>max(m))m=rbind(cumsum((m=t(m[,ncol(m):1]))[1,]),m);min(m[m>=x])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BCsMgFEXR7fwHDnTaYjYSHKQ2oR98Boy2QunabTrr@Fy4ZWxajvpcUlv92FqOVfcs3dBXccD79dC0Sp@4dCFAX26a7xIbj0aRX8bZ5Linky8uALMzAYa4UvNpnHwP@Px9xFlrMb4)